# Load primefaces tow dynamic selectOneMenu with @OneToMany relation

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces, one-to-many, selectonemenu

I want to load tow primefaces selectOneMenu but with only one select from dataBase.

**Class Country:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class Country implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = -2160543740997716714L;


@Id
@Column(name = "ID_COUNTRY")
private Long idTCountry;

@Column(name = "LIBELLE_COUNTRY")
private String libelleCountry;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="country")
  private List<City> Cities;
```

**Class City**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITY")
public class City implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1617401771255693322L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID_CITY")
private Long idCity;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY")
private Country country;

@Column(name = "LIBELLE")
private String libelle;
```

What do I do in XHTML to load those tow selectOneMenu dynamically ?

I did this but it didin't work:

```
        <p:outputLabel for="country" value="Country: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{countryView.selectedCountry}"  style="width:150px">
            <p:ajax listener="#{countryView.onTypeChange}" update="city" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{countryView.countries}" itemLabel="#{selectedType.libelleCountry}" var="selectedCountry" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel for="city" value="City: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{countryView.selectedCity}" style="width:150px">
            <f:selectItems value="#{countryView.selectedCountry.cities}" itemLabel="#{selectedCity.libelle}" var="selectedCity" itemValue="#{selectedCity}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Can any one help me to do this Please ?

Comment: In java all objects are loaded correctly and in xhtml the list (selectOneMenu) of countries has been loaded BUT the list of cities is always empty. I think that I should modify the properties of selectOneMenu city in XHTML but I dont know how.

Comment: for the Primefaces-part just take the code from the Primefaces showcase (if you havent already done it): http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml. For the JPA-part, ore you sure cities is initialized (per default, collections are lazy loaded, at least with hibernate)

Comment: to help you further, we need your backing bean code (countryView)

Comment: In the showcase the second list is loaded by an Ajax event and not automatically:  <p:ajax listener="#{dropdownView.onCountryChange}" update="city" />.  onCountryChange():  cities = data.get(country);

Comment: In JPA all is OK. When I inspect a country Object it contains a list of city objects. Si cities is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  Raphael Roth I have to do this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="country", cascade =    CascadeType.ALL)
private List<City> cities;
```

And of course I have to add converters also:

```
    <p:outputLabel for="city" value="City: " />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{countryView.selectedCity}" style="width:150px"  converter="#{cityConverter}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{countryView.selectedCountry.cities}" itemLabel="#{selectedCity.libelle}" var="selectedCity" itemValue="#{selectedCity}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

And as you see I dont need a listener in ajax event:

```
 <p:ajax update="city" />
```